# Jquery global click and submit interception not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this cookie detection function that I found from another question that I want to implement. I decided to use a global click interceptor to check if my cookie exists before proceeding with the action.

```
$(document).on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var cookie = getCookie("cookieName");
    if (cookie == null) {
        alert("not exists");
    } else {
        alert("exists");
    }
    console.log(event);
    event.currentTarget.submit();
});
```

The issue now is that when I submit it, I get the alert and then this error pops up:

> event.currentTarget.submit is not a function

I tried to log the console and could see my form event inside.

I'm unsure of what I'm missing.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you're saying? My intention is to continue with the submit action after the check is done.

Comment: it says #document. does this mean I should pass the id of the form that I want to submit each time then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`Event.currentTarget` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget):

> The `currentTarget` read-only property of the Event interface identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. **It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to `Event.target`, which identifies the element on which the event occurred...**

In your case, "the element to which the event handler has been attached" is `document`. You don't want to submit the `document` (nor can you); you want to submit the *`form`*.

Try `event.target.submit();` instead:

```
$(document).on("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var cookie = getCookie("cookieName");
    if (cookie == null) {
        alert("not exists");
    } else {
        alert("exists");
    }
    event.target.submit();
});
```

```js
$(document).on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(`event.target: ${event.target.constructor.name}`);
  console.log(`event.currentTarget: ${event.currentTarget.constructor.name}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```